# Keep UI responsive while fetch data from internet alternative of Handler postDelayed

Tags: java, android

I have a ArrayList that I fetch from internet. Now I am performing the list retrieval using Handler postdelayed. Like below in the onCreate of the activity.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

            lis_dat.remove(lis_dat.size() - 1);
            if (gri_not_lis) {
                rv_3r_ada.notifyItemRemoved(lis_dat.size());
            } else {
                rv_3r_2c_ada.notifyItemRemoved(lis_dat.size());
            }
            List<String> lis_of_dat;
            int cou = 0, pos = lis_dat.size();
            String gen_sta, gen_end, gen_mon;
            if (yea) {
                String[] mon_sym = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
                lis_of_dat = Arrays.asList(mon_sym);
            } else {
                int how_man;
                if (lis_is_new) {
                    how_man = 500;
                } else {
                    how_man = 15;
                }
                if (day_in_bet(sta, end) <= how_man) {
                    gen_sta = sta;
                    gen_end = end;
                } else {
                    gen_sta = sta;
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(db_han.con_dat(sta));
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, how_man);
                    gen_end = USE_DAT.format(cal.getTime());
                }
                lis_of_dat = gen_dat_in_bet(gen_sta, gen_end);
            }
            for (String dat : lis_of_dat) {
                if (yea) {
                    Date date = get_mon_dat(dat, YEA.format(db_han.con_dat(sta)));
                    gen_sta = get_mon_fir_or_las_dat(date, true);
                    gen_end = get_mon_fir_or_las_dat(date, false);
                    gen_mon = dat;
                } else {
                    gen_sta = dat;
                    gen_end = null;
                    gen_mon = mon;
                }
                add_to_lis(gen_sta, gen_end, gen_mon, pos, gri_not_lis);
                pos++;
            }
            pos_f[0] = pos;
            cou_f[0] = cou;
            is_loa = false;
        }

}, 1000);
```

Now my question is this 1000 milliseconds here may vary in different devices. On whom the UI will stay frozen. So what's the alternative of this. Instead of waiting for 1 sec how can I wait till the UI loading is complete and then I do the retrieval?

I could use AsyncTask but then the task will stay running till the task is complete even if I go to another activity. but i don't need the task running after onPause is called. So how do I do it?

Comment: use RX2 Java, android

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask which running in separate thread, your keeps UI responsive . You can cancel it in onPause of Activity  by calling **asyncTaskRunner.cancel(true)  **

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String resp;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return resp;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {


    }
}
```

Comment: I know. But as I said I don't need the task running when I pause the activity. but this thread like this will stay running even after on pause

Comment: You can cancel it in onPause of Activity by calling  asyncTaskRunner.cancel(true)

Answer (score 0):

> You can save instance of handler and then remove all call backs in
>   onPause of the activity.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

  handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            // do you task here

        },1000);

 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // this is important
    }
```

> And if you want something which do not freeze UI without any delay,
>   there you go

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
            // Do you task here without any delay it will not freeze the UI
        });
    }
```

> You can also try this,

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // Your Task Here, put your all calculations Here

        }
    }
```

**and then in onCrate()**

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(new MyThread());
```

**and then in onPause() or onDestory()**

```
 executor.shutdownNow();// this will stop the thread instantly
```

Comment: My question was how do I not use the Handler postdelayed for 1000 ms.

Comment: Okay you can use Executers , let me edit the answer

Comment: @itsRedwan please check now i have edited the answer and let me know if this what u want or not

Comment: This isn't working. Looks like the list now is never being loaded.

Comment: can you provide the complete code? i want to see what you are trying to acheive

Comment: so its just calculations and no networking involved right? so i think think executors should work but we can try it on seprate thread as well , i will edit the answer please check

Comment: check now , you can creat MyThread class within your activity @itsRedwan